# Why does Rails make layout selection a controller concern instead of a view concern? Can I choose a layout from a view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout

Maybe there's a technical/implementation reason for it, but it seems to me that "layout" is about as clearly part of the view layer as it can be, yet Rails seems to only allow specifying the layout at a controller level.

My controller shouldn't care about layouts... the templates should.  Is there any way to specify which layout to use from within the .erb file?

Something like:

```
<%= with_layout :news_feed do %>

  <p>
    My markup in here.
  </p>

<% end %>
```

Or any other implementation you can think of... but the documentation only seems to refer to the layout from the controller perspective.

Maybe it wouldn't be too hard to implement a `with_layout` helper.

EDIT | I found exactly what I was looking for:

```
<% render :layout => "some_layout" do %>
  <p>
    My markup here
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Now provided your ActionController has:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  layout nil
```

Then each template can select its own layout, using this approach.

If you place a layout in app/layouts, with a name that matches the controller, that layout will be used, so you don't strictly have to specify if they are all the same.  Either way, the dude how writes your templates now has full control of it, not the dude who's writing the controllers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some research and I did not find any solution similar to what you're looking for.

I think that might have to do with the fact that specifying a layout other than the default can be done by naming a file `your_controllers_name.html.erb` under `app/views/layouts`. This can remove any logic from your controller if the same layout is always used for a specific controller. Maybe this is what you're looking for? If you do not have a matching controller name for a layout, then the default `application.html.erb` will be used.

If you need to render a different layout conditionally, then that decision does need to be made in your controller. Otherwise you would push down the decision-making logic into your view. Your view should not have to make the decision about what layout it needs because the controller is there to make decisions and set up any necessary data that a view requires.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I got this from the docs, but it just seems kinda weird really.  Our team is quite clearly split into designers and developers, and the designers should never have to be touching our controllers.  Maybe we'll just fall back to using an empty layout with includes for top and bottom portions included by the front-end guys.  Or maybe I'll investigate a solution that allows a `with_layout` block.  We have four or five "standard" layouts, and they're not necessarily linked with any specific controllers... it just depends on the page content.

Comment: @d11wtq - I get where you're coming from, although your designers still wouldn't need to touch controller code right? They could just create the layouts in the layouts directory and then the developers would add any conditional code if need be. In general though you could probably get away with the controller naming convention scheme for 95% of the time.

Comment: @d11wtq, did that code block you posted solve your problem? If so you really should make it an answer so you can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Some statements:

Layout is about rendering.
Layout can be called only once.
Views - are the top (last) level of rendering.
Controller - is a first level rendering layer.

So I can say that only place where we can set layout - is a controller. If we could set layout from views, so we will get problems with nested layouting, because each view (partial as well) will call its own layout.

It is easy and clear how controller sets layout. And it is unclear and messy if we are setting parent level view from its children.

What are you talking about - is yielding (`content_for`) and partials (`render :partial`). It is great tools and they work perfect.

Comment: Well I would have to disagree that it's a controller concern.  That might be the easiest solution, but the layout is basically part of the template; it has nothing to do with the controller.  I know that the place we set it is in the controller... but this is a Rails thing, not a MVC thing.

Comment: Also, with regards to nested layouts, it would be quite possible to have sub-layouts, for things like drawing boxes around content etc... it's basically just saying: "I'm about to generate some content, and I want this file to render that content".  Whether or not that file contains <html> tags and other top-level stuff is neither here nor there ;)

Comment: @d11wtq, `for things like drawing boxes around content etc` that is just what partials do. You don't need sublayouts at all. Layout - is a single file without any sublayouts. Sublayouts are __partials__. Controller concern is to choose a layout as a start point for rendering. Actualy what controller do - __is rendering__. So it is controller work to choose layout.